# Overriding == Operator is not working and exits program

Tags: ruby

I am trying to override the `==` operation as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186815/override-operator-in-ruby). I created `==` as so:

```
class Point
  def ==(g)
    p'Never reaches here'
    if @x==g.grid
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```

I am calling the method as so:

```
def home? (gridPoint,point)
  if point==gridPoint
    do something
  end
```

When I run an application, `"Never reaches here"` is never printed, and the application skips the rest of the code and exits.

If I print `gridPoint` and `Point` right before the `==`, I can see they are both points. Why does the program seem to have never entered the `==` method?

I tried `point.==(gridPoint)`. This does not work either, and also defies the purpose of trying to clean the code.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hmm. It seems to work fine for me

Comment: Working for me as well. The class `Point` should be capitalized, right? Might be an error in `gridPoint` or `point`, that they perhaps aren't instances of the class you declared.

Comment: I think I'm missing sth. How do you guys can tell it is working for you, if the code supplied is incomplete? @Bawn, could you please update your question with some code which allows to reproduce the error - where does `@x` come from? What is `grid` method? What is `gridPoint` and how is it differnet form `Point`?

Answer (score -2):

I think I have some suggestions why your exact code doesn't work

1. Class names should always be constants. This means you must capitalize the first letter!
2. You need to declare your `==` method as a class method not an instance method.
3. Along with #2 you need to call it using the class name not from the objects instance

`class Point`

```
      attr_accessor :x

      def initialize(string)
        @x == string
      end

       def self.== (g)
          p'Never reaches here'
          @x==(g) ? true : false
       end

      def home? (gridpoint, point)
        Point == (gridpoint)
      end
    end

    n = Point.new("Schylar")
    puts n.home?("Schylar","Schylar")
```

Comment: No, I disagree with 2. and 3., which ruins the object-oriented aspect of the equals method. `==` should work just fine as an instance method. The code you've written above deviates strongly from what OP wants, and has several peculiarities - why is there a `point` argument for `home?`?

Comment: I disagree in the statement that it ruins the OO aspect, but please write your version that works when wrote as an instance variable.

Comment: Hm, after looking at OP's specific implementation of `==`, I see where you're coming from, but that really isn't a correct usage of `==` in the first place. I'm not sure what's wrong with OP's code, there really isn't enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I agree, OP needs to clarify with all of his code. Specifically @x and g.grid!