# Can we override operators in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

in a case...such as

```
(10 + 20) * 10
=> 300
```

the expression fragment enclosed in parentheses is evaluated before the higher precedence multiplication.So does it applies to other operators as well.Can i override other operators such as `<< !`...etc

Comment: I don't understand this question. What does operator precedence have to do with (existing) ability to override operators?

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When humans evaluate expressions, they usually do so starting at the left of the expression and working towards the right. For example, working from left to right we get a result of 300 from the following expression:

```
10 + 20 * 10 = 300
```

This is because we, as humans, add `10` to `20`, resulting in `30` and then multiply that by `10` to arrive at `300`. Ask Ruby to perform the same calculation and you get a very different answer:

```
> 10 + 20 * 10
=> 210
```

This is a direct result of operator precedence. Ruby has a set of rules that tell it in which order operators should be evaluated in an expression. Clearly, Ruby considers the multiplication operator (*) to be of a higher precedence than the addition (+) operator.

### Overriding Operator Precedence

The precedence built into Ruby can be overridden by surrounding the lower priority section of an expression with parentheses. For example:

```
> (10 + 20) * 10
=> 300
```

In the above example, the expression fragment enclosed in parentheses is evaluated before the higher precedence multiplication.

for more info refer this :

- http://rubysnippets.com/2013/01/25/operator-overloading-in-ruby/
- [Override == operator in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186815/override-operator-in-ruby)

I hope this makes you clear to understand :)

Answer (score 2):

yes you can,you can do it like this

```
class String
  def << str
    self + "*" + str
  end
end

puts "str" << "sss"
```