# check if array includes an instance with a certain value for an instance variable Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

So if a have this code:

```
class A
    def initialize(type)
        @type = type
    end
end

instance = A.new(2)
another_instance = A.new(1)

array = [instance, another_instance]
```

is there a way to check if `array` includes an instance of `A` where `@type` is equal to a certain value?  say, 2?  like the `include?` method but where instead of checking for an instance of a certain class, it also checks the instance variables of that class?

Comment: Have look at [Override == operator in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186815/override-operator-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using an`attr_reader` for this one unless you plan on modifying the `type` somewhere after (in that case use `attr_accessor` which is both a writer and reader)

```
class A
  attr_reader :type
  def initialize(type)
    @type = type
  end
end
instance = A.new(2)
another_instance = A.new(1)

array = [instance, another_instance]

array.select do |item|
  item.type == 2
end
=>[#<A:0x00000000dc3ea8 @type=2>]
```

Here I am iterating through an array of instances of `A` and selecting only the ones that meet the condition `item.type == 2`

Answer (score 1):

You can just refer to the instance variable.

```
> array.any? { |item| item.is_a?(A) }
=> true
> array.any? { |item| item.instance_variable_get(:@type) == 1 }
=> true
> array.select { |item| item.instance_variable_get(:@type) == 1 }
=> [#<A:0x007fba7a12c6b8 @type=1>]
```

Or, use attr_accessor in your class, to make it way easier

```
class A
  attr_accessor :type
  def initialize(type)
    @type = type
  end
end
```

then you can do `something = A.new(5); something.type`

Comment: You *can* use `instance_variable_get`, but you definitely shouldn't. Instance variables are private by design. If you want their value to be public, that's what `attr_reader` or `attr_accessor` is for.

Comment: @Jordan, that's true, but if the question is taken literally that's the only way.