# Confusion with the output came from a user-defined instance method calling from IRB

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

```
class Object
  def all_equals(o)
    ops = [:==, :===, :eql?, :equal?]
    Hash[ops.map(&:to_s).zip(ops.map {|s| send(s, o) })]
  end
end
```

***OUTPUT***

```
"a".all_equals "a" # => {"=="=>true, "==="=>true, "eql?"=>true, "equal?"=>false}
```

Can anyone help me by breaking the code as much as deep can to see how it gave such output?

Just wanted to know the logic how it works to give some output

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156955/whats-the-difference-between-equal-eql-and

Comment: But how the internal logic goes on to reach the output can you tell me that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self
# => "a"

o
# => "a"

ops.map(&:to_s)
# => [:==, :===, :eql?, :equal?].map(&:to_s)
# => ["==", "===", "eql?", "equal?"]

ops.map {|s| send(s, o) }
# => [:==, :===, :eql?, :equal?].map {|s| "a".send(s, "a") }
# => ["a".send(:==, "a"), "a".send(:===, "a"), "a".send(:eql?, "a"), "a".send(:equal?, "a")]
# => ["a" == "a", "a" === "a", "a".eql?("a"), "a".equal?("a")]
# => [true, true, true, false]

ops.map(&:to_s).zip(ops.map {|s| send(s, o) })
# => ["==", "===", "eql?", "equal?"].zip([true, true, true, false])
# => [["==", true], ["===", true], ["eql?", true], ["equal?", false]]

Hash[ops.map(&:to_s).zip(ops.map {|s| send(s, o) })]
# => Hash[[["==", true], ["===", true], ["eql?", true], ["equal?", false]]]
# => {"==" => true, "===" => true, "eql?" => true, "equal?" => false}
```

Comment: `+1` to you to show your interest and and explanation! that's the logic was running behind of the code! okay i understood!