# Is this the correct way to test whether an object is an instance of a class?

Tags: ruby, class, instance

```
object.class == String
object.class === String
```

I initially used the first `==` and it was working fine but [this](http://davidrupp.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/regarding-ruby-instanceof-kindof-and.html) site talks about just `===`.

What is the difference when used in this manner?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between equal?, eql?, ===, and ==?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156955/whats-the-difference-between-equal-eql-and)

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another way:

```
a = "foo"
a.is_a?(String)
```

**NOTE**

```
a = "foo"
a.kind_of?(String)
```

`kind_of?` and `is_a?` behave the same way. `instance_of?` will only return true if is an instance of the class and does not account for subclass.

**Example**

```
10.class 
#=> Fixnum
10.is_a?(Integer)
#=> true
10.kind_of?(Integer)
#=> true
10.instance_of?(Integer)
#=> false
```

Comment: What does the `==` and `===` do? Do they differ?

Comment: `==` tests whether the conditions given are equal, e.g. `1 == 1` yields `true`. The `===` operator normally tests if the element to the right is included in the element to the left. Each class has kind of it's own implementation for `===`.

Comment: In addition to @nicooga statement, note that "a" === "b" yields false as "a" and "b" are two different objects.