# Own class with spaceship operator does not work for LCS Diff

Tags: ruby, diff, comparable

I'm trying to implement a custom class including the comparable mixin. Later the class is used to do a diff. The class looks like

```
class Element
  include Comparable
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def <=>(other)
    @name <=> other.name
  end
end
```

Now some test values with two added entries compared to a.

```
a = Array.new
b = Array.new

a.push Element.new('y1')
a.push Element.new('y2')
a.push Element.new('y4')
a.push Element.new('x1')
a.push Element.new('x2')
a.push Element.new('x4')

b.push Element.new('y1')
b.push Element.new('y2')
b.push Element.new('y3')
b.push Element.new('y4')
b.push Element.new('x1')
b.push Element.new('x2')
b.push Element.new('x3')
b.push Element.new('x4')
```

And now run diff between both arrays

```
puts Diff::LCS.diff(a, b).inspect
```

I would expect two added objects now but it finds 8 changes... Any ideas why?

```
[[["-", 2, #<Element:0x007fa9fb567898 @name="y4">],
  ["-", 3, #<Element:0x007fa9fbc69830 @name="x1">],
  ["-", 4, #<Element:0x007fa9fbca3378 @name="x2">],
  ["+", 2, #<Element:0x007fa9fb5e5e78 @name="y3">],
  ["+", 3, #<Element:0x007fa9fb606920 @name="y4">],
  ["+", 4, #<Element:0x007fa9fb625848 @name="x1">],
  ["+", 5, #<Element:0x007fa9fb647da8 @name="x2">],
  ["+", 6, #<Element:0x007fa9fbde8670 @name="x3">]]]
```

If we run the test with

```
a = Array.new
b = Array.new

a.push 'y1'
a.push 'y2'
a.push 'y4'
a.push 'x1'
a.push 'x2'
a.push 'x4'

b.push 'y1'
b.push 'y2'
b.push 'y3'
b.push 'y4'
b.push 'x1'
b.push 'x2'
b.push 'x3'
b.push 'x4'
```

Everything works as expected:

```
[[["+", 2, "y3"]],
 [["+", 6, "x3"]]]
```

Comment: @muistooshort added the output. It's really strange, I can't see why it does not work. The result is however correct, it's just not the minimal possible diff that describes the changes.

Comment: What is `Diff::LCS.diff(a, b)`? Is it standard Ruby module (1.9.3/2.n)?

Comment: @DarekNędza in the example I used https://github.com/halostatue/diff-lcs but it looks like it is the same with any other diff algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspecting from source of [`Diff::LCS`](https://github.com/halostatue/diff-lcs/blob/master/lib/diff/lcs/internals.rb#L73), the elements in sequences are used as hash key.

The `Element` class you wrote mixed the Comparable module, it got the `==` method there. However, it doesn't have `eql?` and `hash` method override, which is used by the `Hash` to determine the key comparison.

With you `Element` class, we have

```
irb(main):013:0> a = Element.new("a")
=> #<Element:0x002ae4ce402da0 @name="a">
irb(main):014:0> b = Element.new("a")
=> #<Element:0x002ae4ce409ec0 @name="a">
irb(main):015:0> a == b
=> true
irb(main):016:0> a.eql? b
=> false
irb(main):017:0> a.hash == b.hash
=> false
irb(main):018:0> h = {}
=> {}
irb(main):019:0> h[a] = 1
=> 1
irb(main):020:0> h[b]
=> nil
```

This affects the LCS calculation.

The fix is to add the `eql?` and `hash` method for the `Element` class, I think.

```
class Element
  include Comparable
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def <=>(other)
    @name <=> other.name
  end

  def eql? other
    other.class == Element and self.name == other.name
  end

  def hash
    @name.hash ^ Element.hash
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect! That's it :) Could you comment the hash function a little bit? What do we achieve by XORing the both hashes?

Comment: @Paddi91 You can take a look at [What's the difference between equal?, eql?, ===, and ==?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156955), [Hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Generally, if a equals b, then hash(a) equals hash(b); however, hash(a) equals hash(b) doesn't imply a equals b.