# eql? behavior after redefining Object#hash

Tags: ruby

[Ruby API](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F) says:

> The eql? method returns true if obj and other refer to the same hash key.

I changed the hash method for `Object`:

```
class Object
 def hash
   1
 end
end

Object.new.hash == Object.new.hash
# => true

Object.new.eql? Object.new
# => false
```

I don't understand why the second statement returns `false`; according to Ruby Object API above, it should return `true`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between equal?, eql?, ===, and ==?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156955/whats-the-difference-between-equal-eql-and)

Comment: I'm not sure what documentation you've been reading, but: "eql? returns true only if obj and other are the same object." http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F

Comment: That's not what the docs say, and "the same hash key" isn't really relevant to the code you post.

Comment: @DaveNewton That is actually what the doc says. Please see my answer.

Comment: @sawa Not the docs I'm reading.

Comment: I added a link to the question, which is the one I am mentioning. It that different from what you read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F) bug. You read it correctly, but the documentation is contradictory.

- On the one hand, the documentation says:

  > The eql? method returns true if obj and other refer to the same hash key.

  from which you can expect as you did in your question:

  ```
  Object.new.eql? Object.new
  # => true
  ```
- On the other hand, it also says:

  > For objects of class Object, eql? is synonymous with ==.

  where the definition of `==` is given as:

  > At the Object level, == returns true only if obj and other are the same object.

  It logically follows that:

  > For objects of class Object, eql? returns true only if obj and other are the same object.

  from which you should expect:

  ```
  Object.new.eql? Object.new
  # => false
  ```

So the documentation makes contradictory claims. You relied on one of them, and made an expectation, but looking at the actual result, the reality seems to support the second claim.

Comment: Two objects `a`, `b` are ***the same hash key*** if for a hash `h`, `h[a]` and `h[b]` refers to the same object.

Comment: @ArieShaw What are you mentioning about? Are you confusing hash objects with hash function?

Comment: The documentation is definitely confusing in this case. If you read the doc for `Object#hash` it makes it a little clearer that Hash keys in Ruby rely on _both_ `eql?` and `hash`.

Comment: Are there any bug reports for this documentation bug?

Comment: @sawa No. I just don't understand why you imply `Object.new.eql? Object.new` from *The eql? method returns true if obj and other refer to the same hash key*. `eql?` method is used in `Hash` to determine the equality of the keys. If two object `a`, `b` has the same `.hash`, for a Hash `h`, `h[a]` and `h[b]` may refer to the same bucket in the underlying implementation. However, they refer to the same value if and only if `a.hash == b.hash && a.eql? b`. (Ruby may have special treatment with `String` and `Symbol`) http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-hash

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I haven't reported any. You can, if you want.

Answer (score 2):

That's not what the docs say, and "the same hash key" isn't really relevant to the code you post.

`hash` creates a hash key, with the *implication* that `a.eql?(b)` *means* `a.hash == b.hash`. That's different than breaking `hash` and expecting an unmodified `eql?` to work the way you expect.

`eql?` must be overridden to provide the semantics you want, e.g., a custom class could override `eql?` to provide a domain-specific equivalency. The above `hash` contract implications would still need to be followed if you want other code to work appropriately.

(This is similar to the Java mantra "override `hashCode` if you override `equals`, e.g., http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/why-always-override-hashcode-if-overriding-equals/20.)

Answer (score 1):

You're creating two new objects, they will never be the same.

```
a = Object.new
=> #<Object:0x007fd16b35c8b8>
b = Object.new
=> #<Object:0x007fd16b355540>
```

And I will refer you back to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156955/whats-the-difference-between-equal-eql-and)