# Ruby Validation When Adding to Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am really new in Ruby and I am on the last step to finish my project, when I'm trying to add appointment I have to change if doctor works in that time. I don't know how to do this :(

It is how my db works:

In appointment I have data_wizyty (visit_date), doctor_id and godzina_wizyty(visit_time) - it is in my adding form.

In schedules I have:
dzien_tygodnia(day_of_the_week), poczatek_pracy(start_working), koniec_pracy(end_working) and doctors_workplace_id

In doctors_workplace:
doctor_id, schedule_id, clinic_id

I want to check if doctor is available in any of the clinic in choosen date and time :)
Please help me with this :)
I have already validated if date and time is unique with:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :doctor_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:data_wizyty, :godzina_wizyty], message: 'Ten termin jest juz zajety!' }
end
```

I need to check if it is unique and if doctor works.

Appointment:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :doctor_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:data_wizyty, :godzina_wizyty], message: 'Ten termin jest juz zajety!' }
    after_initialize :aInit
    after_save :aSave

    belongs_to :patient
    belongs_to :doctor
    belongs_to :schedule
    belongs_to :refferal
    belongs_to :clinic

    has_many :employees

    include MultiStepModel

    def self.total_steps
        3
    end

    def aInit 
        @wymaga_Potwierdzenia = true 
    end

    def aSave
        if self.refferal_id == nil
            @potwierdzona = false
        else
            @potwierdzona = true
        end
        if self.wymaga_Potwierdzenia == false
            @potwierdzona = true
        end
    end

end
```

Schedule:

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :appointments
    belongs_to :clinic
    belongs_to :doctors_workplace

    def full_schedule
        "#{dzien_tygodnia} : #{poczatek_pracy} - #{koniec_pracy}"
    end

end
```

Doctors_workplace:

```
class DoctorsWorkplace < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :schedules
belongs_to :doctor
belongs_to :clinic_surgery

end
```

Now I have something like this :

```
def check_doctor_available
        if Schedule.where(doctor: doctor, dzien_tygodnia: data_wizyty.wday)
               .where('poczatek_pracy < ? and koniec_pracy > ?', godzina_wizyty, godzina_wizyty).empty?
      self.errors.add(:doctor, message: 'nie pracuje w tym terminie!')
    end
```

It's what I have now:

```
def check_doctor_available
        if DoctorsWorkplace.where(doctor_id: doctor_id) and
           Schedule.where(doctors_workplace_id: ????, dzien_tygodnia: data_wizyty.wday)
               .where('poczatek_pracy < ? and koniec_pracy > ?', godzina_wizyty, godzina_wizyty).empty?
      self.errors.add(:doctor, message: 'nie pracuje w tym terminie!')
    end
```

Comment: Can you show us what the 3 models & their associations look like?

Comment: @Anthony question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom validation. Create a private method in appointment that checks if the doctor is available at the given date/time.

```
validate :check_doctor_available

private
def check_doctor_available
  #your implementation
end
```

Take a look at [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-validators) if you have any doubts what to write in your custom validation method.

Comment: I think I have to check which day is choosen(Monday,Tuesday etc...) and then chech all doctor_workplace for all this doctor's records, then check if choosen day is in Schedules with this doctors_workplace_id is dzien_tygodnia(but how with the day names in db...) later check the time between poczatek_pracy and koniec_pracy :) But I have no idead how to code this :P

Comment: You got it. Cannot give you the implementation though.

Comment: How check if something equal something else ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156955/whats-the-difference-between-equal-eql-and

Comment: please check my updated question and correct my mistakes, I don't know what put there - "???" –  smiaro 5 mins ago