# Why does comparing a decimal to int succeed?

Tags: ruby

This is confusing. Why does this happen?

```
2.0 == 2   # => true
2.0.eql? 2 # => false
```

Comment: It would be inconvenient if it didn't.

Comment: What is confusing? The fact that `==` and `eql?` behave differently? If they behaved the same, then there would be no point for them both to exist.

Comment: There are so many result such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156955/whats-the-difference-between-equal-eql-and), and offical documents alse has [explanation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)

Comment: Somehow it hadn't mattered until I came across finding the index in an array.[1,2.0,3].index(2) returns 1, which seemed wrong. This threw me off and I started to question fundamentals.

Comment: Related (not duplicate) Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25986896/1301972

Comment: There is so much interest in the question and the answer and comments have depth. I learnt a lot and the downvote is worth it!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because ruby tries to do a type-conversion with `==` but not with `eql?`

... and like @sawa said - it'd be inconvenient if that were not an option available to us. Comparing `0.0` with `0` for instance is really useful, and most of the time, whether an object is an int or a decimal doesn't *really* matter. (is `30` minutes the same as `30.0` minutes? do we care that one has `.0` on the end?)

Comment: I noticed that `2==3` invokes `Fixnum#==` whereas both `2.0==3.0` and `2==3.0` invoke `Comparable#==`. I'm especially curious why `Float#==` wasn't used in the first case.

Comment: because 2 isn't a `Float`... it's an `Int`... therefore they can't use the standard `Float` comparison - which only works if they're both `Float`... otherwise they default to their super-classes `==` method, which presumably comes form the `Comparable` module.

Comment: When they're both Fixnums, then `Fixnum#==` is used, as expected. However, I redefined `Comparable#==` and found that it was being used for both `2.0==3.0` and `2==3.0`. It makes sense to me that Ruby would defer to `Comparable#==` when there are different numeric types, but I can't understand why `Float#==` wasn't used for `2.0==3.0`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `2.0 == 3.0` does call `Float#==` which in turn calls `Comparable#==`

Comment: @Stefan, what then is the purpose of having `Float#==`? (I'm not questioning what you're saying--it must be true.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland it was my fault: *my* `Float#==` implementation was calling `Comparable#==` because of `super` (and doing so returned wrong results). Ruby's `Float#==` implementation does not call `Comparable#==`. It handles everything itself, just like `Fixnum#==`.

Comment: If everyone learned so much from the question, I did, then why the downvote, why not allow the asking of fundamental questions even if they are documented.

Comment: Hover your mouse over the down-vote button and you can see a list of things that people should down-vote for... it's not about whether the question is fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

### Numeric Type Conversions and Equality

Your question asks:

> This is confusing. Why does this happen?
>
> ```
> 2.0 == 2   # => true  
> 2.0.eql? 2 # => false
> ```

This is [documented behavior](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F).

> At the Object level, == returns true only if obj and other are the same object. Typically, this method is overridden in descendant classes to provide class-specific meaning...Numeric types, for example, perform type conversion across ==, but not across eql?

The documentation even gives these examples to illustrate:

```
1 == 1.0     #=> true
1.eql? 1.0   #=> false
```

In contrast, [Float#eql?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Float.html#method-i-eql-3F) says:

> Returns true only if obj is a Float with the same value as float. Contrast this with Float#==, which performs type conversions.