# Does Ruby auto-promote numeric values for comparison?

Tags: ruby, jruby, rubymine

Why on earth does comparing a float value of 1.0, to an integer value of 1, return true?

```
puts '1.0'.to_i
puts '1.0'.to_i == 1.0 #so 1 == 1.0 is true?
puts 1.0 == 1 #wtf?
```

Does Ruby only read the first part of the floatin point value and then short circuit? Wuld someone be able to explain with a link to some documentation please? I have flipped through the API but I don't even know what to look for in this case...

Comment: Ruby checks whole value, not only the first part. Try `1.1 == 1`.

Comment: I thought as much. But that doens't explain why my int value of 1 is equal to my float value of 1.0

Comment: Search for **coerce**

Comment: @falsetru coerce does not affect `==`.

Comment: "Why on earth does comparing a float value of 1.0, to an integer value of 1, return true?" They are just different representations of the same number. Of course, they are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, `==` is a method. That means to understand it you need to look at the specific class calling it.

```
1 == 1.0
```

The caller is `1`, a Fixnum. So you need to look at [Fixnum#==](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Fixnum.html#method-i-3D-3D).

```
1.0 == 1
```

The caller is `1.0`, a Float. So you need to look at [Float#==](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Float.html#method-i-3D-3D).

A surprising result of this is that `==` *is not necessarily symmetric*: `a == b` and `b == a` could call completely different methods and return completely different results. In this case though, both `==` methods end up calling the C function `rb_integer_float_eq` which converts both operands to the same data type before comparing them.

Comment: Max you answered this question perfectly. I checked the API and you are indeed correct.

Answer (score 5):

`==` compares the value, the value of `1.0` is equal to `1` in math, so it's not much surprising. To compare value as well as type, you can use `eql?`:

```
1.0 == 1
#=> true
1.0.eql? 1
#=> false
```

Comment: Intuitively, this answer is correct. But this doesn't explain _at all_ how `==` does this.

Answer (score 0):

Most languages will automatically increase the precision of a variable's type in order to perform operations on them such as compare, add, multiply, etc.  They "usually" do not decrease the precision, nor unnecessarily increase it.  E.g. 1/2 = 0, but 1.0/2.0 = 0.5.

Comment: This sounds like a guess, at best.

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=ruby+implicit+type+conversion&source=bl&ots=fJBjAi7ugA&sig=a474yV66is29Hw6Gg0u-aXoQLWQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YttHVJKmLqj_8AH59oDoDw&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAjgK#v=onepage&q=ruby%20implicit%20type%20conversion&f=false

Comment: You should read that section more closely. It says nothing about implicit conversions being used for `==` with Fixnum and Float. My answer details the exact mechanism causing the behavior in the question. tl;dr it works by calling a function _specifically designed_ to compare Fixnums and Floats.

Comment: "Unfortunately, the circumstances under which these implicit conversion methods are called are not well documented."

Comment: Could you speak to me rather than quoting at me? It doesn't matter that the conversions are not well documented: my answer points out the exact code path that is used for this comparison and it has nothing to do with implicit conversion as described in that book.

Comment: The question was "why" it does what it does, not "how".  I believe my answer correctly addresses the "why", yours addresses the "how".  But the issue with referring to the source code is that it's not documented, and will be implementation specific.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there already is a nice answer "[What's the difference between equal?, eql?, ===, and ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156955/whats-the-difference-between-equal-eql-and)" about equality in Ruby, with references and stuff. There is a surprising amount of ways to compare for equality in Ruby, each with its own purpose.

Since mathematical meaning is not enough for you, you can compare differently. Like, say, `eql?` that is heavily used in `Hash`es to determine if two keys are the same. And it turns out that `1.0` and `1` are **different** keys! his is what I get in IRB of Ruby 2.1.2:

```
> 1.0.eql?(1.0)
 => true 
> 1.eql?(1)
 => true 
> 1.eql?(1.0)
 => false
```

Answer (score -1):

Ruby is coercing the operands of == (as needed) to the same type, then performing a comparison of their numeric values.  This is normally what you want for numeric comparisons.

Comment: Crap, this isn't what I want at all, but I understand the concept of promotion. I guess I will have to use the to_i method when doing comparisons of this type.

Comment: Editing "promoting" to the more accurate term "coercing".  The idea is still the same.

Comment: `coerce` only affects numeric operations (+-*/ etc.). `==` is common to all objects.

Comment: @Max Actually `==` is redefined for most of the core Ruby types. [`Fixnum#==` performs coercion](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/numeric.c#L3265-L3279) just like the other methods you mentioned.

Comment: @toro2k Coercion in Ruby refers to a very specific thing: calling the `coerce` method. Although `Fixnum#==` does try to compare by value by converting operands, it does _not_ perform coercion in this literal sense. If you were to define a new numeric class with a coerce method, you would not get automatic correct behavior with `==`.