# comparison in php using == and === operators

Tags: php

In my application, there are values generated at run time like x, 1x,2,1 etc.
I need to compare these:

as we know,

```
        x  == 1  is false   
       '1x'== 1  is true
       '1' == 1  is true
```

for my application, the first,second cases needs to be false and third needs to be true. if I use ===,

```
       x  === 1    is false   
      '1x'=== 1    is false   
      1'  === 1    is false
```

So both these comparisons i can not use.

I think converting to string and then comparing using `strcmp` will be the best option I have. Please share your thoughts. Any reply is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just compare `'1' === '1'`, i.e. surround the `1` with single quotes?

Comment: == are used to compare values if they are equal and it is less strict than ===.

Comment: I can not do this because all these are generated at run time and no control over values generated. Do you mean to append '' for all and compare? if so it work as it compare everything as string. so is that better way or using strcmp?

Comment: === are used to compare two values and also sees that both the values have the same data-type. === is more better to use than == if you want your values to match exactly.

Comment: this is how php comparision works.... don't like it? change the language perhaps?

Comment: @Robin, i need comparision based on values and no need to have same data types. so ideal choice is ==. but cases like '1x'== 1 are failing where i expect false due to same values

Comment: @itachi, its not about i like it or not. I am trying to solve a problem in php and any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between equal?, eql?, ===, and ==?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156955/whats-the-difference-between-equal-eql-and)

Comment: @iatboy no ,its not duplicate i believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strcmp` would be suitable for this.But you should be aware of its return values.

`Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.`

or you can also use `Regex`

Comment: thanks, even i was having the same opinion. will wait for some other views also now

Comment: hmm..its little complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Use either `strcmp` or `strcasecmp`:

> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.
>   [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)

Comment: @AVC For case insensitive search, use `strcasecmp` as mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following :

```
if(strlen($x) == 1) {
    if ((intval($x) === 1)) {
        echo "Equals";
    }
    else
   {
        echo "Not Equals";
   }
}
   }else
   {
       echo "Not Equals";
   }
```