# Do I need `all` after `where`? Is it redundant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

This might be a silly question.  It's certainly pedantic.

Is there any difference between `MyModel.where(...)` and `MyModel.where(...).all`?

This question was prompted by a deprecation warning I got a few minutes ago:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: This dynamic method is deprecated.
Please use e.g. Post.where(...).all instead.
```

Is that `all` really necessary?

Comment: They both return an AR:Relation, I can't see why that would be suggested.  What method is it calling deprecated?

Comment: It's not really relevant, but it was `MyModel.find_all_by_id(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are equivalent, at least in the way you're probably thinking:

```
Model.where(id: nil) ===    Model.where(id: nil).all # returns true
Model.where(id: nil) ==     Model.where(id: nil).all # returns true
Model.where(id: nil).eql?   Model.where(id: nil).all # returns false
Model.where(id: nil).equal? Model.where(id: nil).all # returns false
```

#### What these equalities tell us (borrowing heavily from [this exceptional answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156955/whats-the-difference-between-equal-eql-and)):

1. Case Equality- sometimes thought of as "If I have a box labeled `a`, does `b` get put in it?
2. "Equality" in the usual thinking.  Are these two things the "same", can I replace one with the other without any impacts, do they return the same thing with the same input
3. `.eql?` and `.equal?` being false confirms that these are two different objects.  Both that their hashes are non-identical and their object identities are non-identical