# Ruby comparison used by 'group_by'

Tags: ruby, group-by

I want to group objects that are virtually the same but not identical like in this case:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :value

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def ==(other)
    (@value - other.value).abs < 0.0001
  end
end
```

With the precision relevant for my implementation, two values differing by 0.0001 can be regarded identical:

```
MyClass.new(1.0) == MyClass.new(1.00001)
# => true
```

I want these to be in the same group:

```
[MyClass.new(1.0), MyClass.new(1.00001)].group_by(&:value)
# => {1.0=>[#<MyClass:0x0000000d1183e0 @value=1.0>], 1.00001=>[#<MyClass:0x0000000d118390 @value=1.00001>]}
```

What comparison is used for `group_by`? Can the built in `group_by` be made to honor the custom `==` method, or is a custom `group_by` method required for this?

Comment: For code style, I'd recommend using `group_by` with a block over redefining `==`, but this is an interesting problem anyways.

Comment: I'm using the SketchUp Ruby API that already implements == or points, lengths and other classes.

Also I'm not sure how a block could be used for this. The block has no access to the already defined groups or previous elements to compare against. For trivial cases like floats you could of course round to 3 decimals or so, but what about other classes?

Comment: I hope my answer helps you out here, TL;DR under the hood it's creating a hash, and the output of the block becomes the key to the hash.

Comment: If the sketchup API implements a `to_h` method or some way of converting element to and from a hash, you could `group_by(&:to_h)`.

Comment: In general, include [Comparable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Comparable.html)  in your class and (re)define `<=>`

Comment: In this case, not all is clear. if 1.0 == 1.00001 == 1.00002 == 1.00003 then 1.0 == any number

Comment: @steenslag Here the question is about hash comparison, which uses `eql?` which `Comparable` does not touch (AFAIK). So including `Comparable` would not help here.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR It appears to me that this issue is because group_by doesn't actually check equality anywhere. It generates the hash, and uses the elements of the array as keys.

Long story:

My first guess here was that it was doing something like `my_arr.map(&:value).group_by { |i| i }`, which would mean that it would be checking the equality of 2 floats instead of 2 MyClasses. To test this, I redefined `==` on a float, and added debugging puts statements to both of our definitions of `==`. Interestingly, nothing was printed. So, I went on over to [the documentation for `group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), and looked at the source code:

```
               static VALUE
enum_group_by(VALUE obj)
{
    VALUE hash;

    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(obj, 0, 0, enum_size);

    hash = rb_hash_new();
    rb_block_call(obj, id_each, 0, 0, group_by_i, hash);
    OBJ_INFECT(hash, obj);

    return hash;
}
```

Notice the last argument to `rb_block_call` -- It's a hash. This hinted to me that under the hood, ruby is doing this:

```
def group_by(&:block)
  h = {}
  self.each do |ele|
    key = block_given? ? block.call(ele) : ele
    h[key] ||= []
    h[key].push(ele)
  end
end
```

When getting a key from a hash, it seems that `==` is not called, and so this attempt to redefine `==` didn't do what you wanted. A way to fix this would be like so:

```
[MyClass.new(1.0), MyClass.new(1.00001)].group_by { |i| i.value.round(2) }
```

Comment: `group_by` uses `hash` + `eql?`

Comment: Thank you @pascalbetz! I didn't know that.

Comment: had to look it up as well... the various ways ruby does comparison are confusing :-)

Answer (score 1):

Group By uses `hash` and `eql?` to determine if a key inside the `Hash` is the same. So something like this should work:

```
class MyClass


 attr_accessor :value

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def ==(other)
    (@value - other.value).abs < 0.0001
  end

  def hash
    rounded_value.hash
  end

  def eql?(other)
    self == other
  end

  def rounded_value
    @value.round(3)
  end
end
```

Please check if this gives you the required precission when marking keys as equal. Otherwise adapt the `rounded_value` method.

Here is a good summary of the equals operators/methods in ruby: [What's the difference between equal?, eql?, ===, and ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156955/whats-the-difference-between-equal-eql-and)