# ruby class and object - different methods of comparison

Tags: ruby

So see the below code:

```
   s1 = "a"
=> "a"
   s1.class
=> String
   s1.class == String
=> true
   s1.class === String
=> false
   String == String
=> true
   String === String
=> false
   String === s1
=> true
   String == s1
=> false
   s1 == String
=> false
   s1 === String
=> false
```

my question is ->

1. why `String == String` evaluates to true but `String === String`
   does not?

Is it because in fact those are different objects and are
        stored in different parts of memory? If yes then why would we
        initialize many Class objects of String? (shouldn't those be kind of
        a singleton?)

String inherits from Object and has Comparable module included.
From Object String gets the `.===` (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)

and from Comparable it gets the `.==` (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Comparable.html#method-i-3D-3D)

From reading the definitions I see that the `.===` is typically the same as `.==` but that's not the case with String. I don't know why though.

2. Why `s1 === String` is false but `String  === s1` is true?

I assume it's because the `.===` implementation on "a" object of a String is not the same that `.===` implementation on the String class, but how does the `.===` (and maybe why does it work in this way) on String work (how does it know it should compare the class of the object and not the value/place in memory)?

Comment: The same thing happens in `case`, `when String` will not match, I assume `case` uses `===`.

Comment: The difference between those two operator is clearly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156955/whats-the-difference-between-equal-eql-and).

Comment: I agree, this question is explained in the duplicate pointed by @Kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right `==` and `===` are different methods on the String class and an instance of String. Have a look at the different documentation for

- [`Module.==`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D)
- [`Module.===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)
- [`String#==`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-3D-3D)
- [`String#===`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)

**Why `String == String` evaluates to `true` but `String === String` does not?**

As you can see in the docs `Module.==` basically means if both sides are the same Object. Is the `String` class the same as the `String` class? Yes. But `Module.===` returns `true` if the right side is an instance of the class on the left. Id `String` an instance of `String`? No.

**Why `s1 === String` is `false` but `String === s1` is `true`?**

`s1 === String` calls `===` on an instance of string. This method returns `true` when both sides are the same object. Are an instance of `String` and the class `Sting` the same object? No. But `String === s1` has – as already explained before the meaning of `is_a?`: Is an instance of `String` an instance of `String`? Yes.

Comment: `.===` returns true is if the right side is the INSTANCE of that class. I've missed that somehow in the docs. thanks!

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that `===` is also called the Case Equality as stated in the [`Object#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) documentation. This operator is called when you provide it as `when` argument. `case 'Hello World!'; when /ello/ then true; end #=> true` or `case 15; when 1..20 then true; end #=> true`

Comment: [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) also uses this operator. `[5, 25, 83, nil, 'hey'].grep(5..30) #=> [5, 25]` or `[5, 25, 83, nil, 'hey'].grep(String) #=> ['hey']`